# php string regex

Tags: php

my code is:

```
$tt='This is a tomato test';
$rr=preg_match('/is(.*)to/',$tt,$match);
print_r($match);
```

From this I am trying to get `" a toma"` output only...but it is giving me:

```
Array
(
    [0] => is is a tomato
    [1] =>  is a toma
)
```

For this regex how can I make it not display the "is" at the beginning of the output strings?

Comment: I think you have to come up with a more specific rule. `/is` will match the first "is" there is, which is "This". If this is not what you want, you have to refine the rule to state "is-not-followed-by-another-is" or "is-as-a-standalone-word" or something along these lines. What's the rule?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution is to note that "this" includes the substring "is" so...

```
$tt='This is a tomato test';
$rr=preg_match('/ is(.*)to/',$tt,$match); // add a space before is.
print_r($match);
```

And `[1]` will be "a toma"

Comment: thanks and how to get rid of the "is" from showing in output please?

Comment: yes works! but how...why does this get rid of the "is" at the beginning of the output?

Comment: As I said, look at the word "this" <- it contains "is" too, so your version of the match was picking this one up, so it included the other "is" as part of the `[1]` back reference, adding the leading space just makes the match more specific.

Answer (score 1):

Another trick is to use a lookbehind assertion `(?<=` whose contents will not be part of the result match:

```
preg_match('/(?<=\bis)(.*)to/', $tt, $match);
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need ia called a lookbehind, described here http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

specicifaclly you want something like `'/(?<= is)(.*)to/'`